# IMAP request for just the most recent emails?

Tags: imap

Is there any way to request just the most recent, say, 100 emails from an IMAP server?

Some background...currently I'm doing the following:

```
a0005 FETCH 1:*
```

If I did this:

```
a0005 FETCH 1:100
```

...these would be the 100 oldest emails, not the newest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using Search command. You can search messages with \Recent flag set.

Comment: I was able to make that work. I use SEARCH to retrieve emails for the last seven days (which is actually what I wanted), then pass the returned index into the FETCH command to get the actual email data. Thanks!